# Socket communication using IPv4

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am using socket communication between two ports on same machines.

On the client side, I use `Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 6666);`

But socket is created using IPv6 and underlying tcp6 is used.

> tcp        0     24 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:57812  ::ffff:127.0.0.1:31210  LAST_ACK    -

Issue is that I can't use flag `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` as I can't block all IPv6 communication.

My question is, if I use `Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666);`, will socket always be created using IPv4? I tested this on my machine and test results show that always IPv4 will be used.

Is there any other way to ensure IPv4 connection? Or using `127.0.0.1` will work fine?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying an IPv4 address like `127.0.0.1` ensures that the socket is for IPv4 only.
 Specifying a hostname like `localhost` instead results in a system dependent behavior: on some systems localhost is declared as both `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) and `::1` (IPv6) while on others localhost is only used for the IPv4 address and a different name like ip6-localhost or similar are used for IPv6.   In the cases where localhost is used both for IPv4 and IPv6 the socket will be usually created using the preferred family which is mostly IPv6.